# In case I have to take a gap year before MS, what can I do in terms of reading and independent study to prepare for graduate school?

Tags: graduate-admissions, time-off, bioinformatics

I will be graduating with a BS in Computer Science in 2017 and have applied to a couple of graduate school to pursue MS in Biomedical Informatics/Bioinformatics. I'm interested in translational research and research in precision/personalized medicine. I am hoping to apply the computer science knowledge in developing pipelines that will facilitate the process of choosing best-fitting medicine/treatment for the patients.

I understand that admission is competitive and well aware that I have a chance of not getting into any of the school that I have applied to. (I have a 3.2 GPA in my BS, 70-75th percentile GRE, and some experience as an intern in my school's Department of Biomedical Informatics.)

My question is that in the worst case when I would have to wait until the following year to apply again (international student here), **what would be the best way to prepare in the meantime in terms of reading journals and independent studies?**

Comment: As it currently stands, I'm of the opinion that this is a "strongly depends on personal factors" questions and should be closed. That said - I think there's an excellent question in there of "how should I prepare for graduate studies while waiting to reapply?".

Comment: @tonysdg I understand where you are coming from, but I disagree. I think I have stated my case pretty clearly with my research interests along with my graduate study plans. I posted this question because I wanted more narrow answers as to how to be better prepared for my prospective field specifically, not just a general "what should I do after applying?"

Comment: I can buy that, but in that case, anything about your GPA/GRE/background is still irrelevant to the question.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic. Please follow suggestion made by @tonysdg.

Comment: To clarify what you want - do you want to know how to prepare to do well in grad school during a gap year, or how to strengthen your application for the next round of applications next year? They might be some very different answers.

Comment: @BrianDHall Hello Brian. I would like to prepare to do well in grad school during a gap year. It would be helpful to find things that would also increase my chances when re-applying to grad schools. For example, learning how to analyze data through R or Python would be something that could help my chances of getting in as well as when I would be participating in a research of some sort.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to get a lab position in your field as a tech - this will allow you to build exactly the type of experience that graduate schools will want, show your dedication and interest in the topic and give you the opportunity to build the type of relationships that lead to convincing recommendation letters.

Comment: Hi Bryan, thanks for the reply. When you say a "tech" what kind of position exactly do you mean?

Comment: @DJB A position in a university laboratory that requires a bachelors degree. I don't know what the exact opportunities would be in CS.